# How to use jwtguard in NestJs websocket?

Tags: node.js

I have my own JwtAuthGuard for routes from auth controller or user. It protects some methods of using routes for users who are not authorized. However, for my chat, I want some methods to be unable to be sent to unauthorized users. I can do something wrong, I'm doing it for the first time
Here is my method:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@SubscribeMessage('message')
async handleMessage(@MessageBody() body: CreateMessageDto, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    const token = socket.handshake.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    console.log(socket);
    return this.chatService.createMessage(body, token);
}
```

JwtAuthGuard:

```
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {AuthGuard} from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
}
```

I understand that I should write JwtSocketAuthGuard, or do I not need to use it here at all?